# SyntaxError: missing } after property list: jqgrid

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

Here is my json data. Json validator shows this is valid in javascript. But I got error of missing } at position 78 (  jquery.jqGrid.src.js:1:78).

```
{"total":1,"PageSize":1,"Page":1,"records":10,"rows":[{"id":"CaSNP01900516","cell":["CaSNP01900516","Ca8","2449175","Substitution","T ","C ","Ca_02342","Uncharacterized protein At1g04910"]},{"id":"CaSNP01900521","cell":["CaSNP01900521","Ca8","2449198","Substitution","T ","G ","Ca_02342","Uncharacterized protein At1g04910"]}]}
```

why this error?. here is my code. which reads the JSON data present in div #abcd and displays in jQgrid. This code was working before for the same data format. is it due to change in version of jquery.jqGrid.src.js file?.

```
<div id="Results">
<div id='title_for_table' style="display:none";>        
<?php include('simple1.php');?>
</div>      

<div id= 'abcd' style="display:none";>      

 {"total":1,"PageSize":1,"Page":1,"records":10,"rows":[{"id":"CaSNP01900516","cell":["CaSNP01900516","Ca8","2449175","Substitution","T ","C ","Ca_02342","Uncharacterized protein At1g04910"]},{"id":"CaSNP01900521","cell":["CaSNP01900521","Ca8","2449198","Substitution","T ","G ","Ca_02342","Uncharacterized protein At1g04910"]}]}    

</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
jQuery(function($) {
var data=  $('#abcd').text();
var data= data.replace(/[\“\”\?]/ig,'\"');
var data = jQuery.trim(data);
var title = $('#title_for_table').text();
var title = jQuery.trim(title);
var typ=  $('#123').text();
var typ = jQuery.trim(typ);
var abc ="Search_opt=snptype&key5="+typ;
if(title=='snpclass' || title == 'keywrd' )
{
jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid({
datatype: "jsonstring",
datastr:data,
colNames:['SNP id','Chromosome','Position','Class','Reference base','Variant base','Gene ID', 'Annotation'],
colModel:[
  {name:'snp_id',index:'snp_id', width:120, align:"center",formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
  return '<a href="?page_id=1120?SNPID='+ cellvalue +'&chr='+rowObject[1]+'&start='+rowObject[2]+'&end='+rowObject[2]+'" target="_blank"><font color="0000FF">'+cellvalue+'</a>';   }},
  {name:'chr',index:'chr', width:100, align:"center"},
  {name:'start_pos',index:'start_pos', width:100, align:"center"},
  {name:'clas',index:'clas', width:100, align:"center" },
  {name:'refbase',index:'refbase', width:100, align:"center"},
  {name:'variantbase',index:'variantbase', width:100, align:"center"},
  {name:'nearest_gene_id',index:'nearest_gene_id', width:100, align:"center"},
  {name:'protein_name',index:'protein_name', align:"center"}
],
pager: '#pager',
rowNum:50,
rowList:[25,50,75,100],
sortname: 'snp_id',
sortorder: "asc",
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,
height: '100%',
width: '100%',
caption:title+" Search Results",
loadComplete: function(reload) {
  jQuery("#tableid").trigger("reloadGrid");
},
 }); 
 jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});

}
});
});
</script>
<table id="tableid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
<div id="genotype" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that fired the error ?

Comment: Which jqGrid is used and which version?

Comment: @TonyTomov : jqGrid  4.4.3  downloaded from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6

Comment: Your main error: you inserted JSON data in the middle of your HTML page (see `<div id= 'abcd' style="display:none";>...</div>`) You can place the data inside of `<script>...</script>` as `var data = ...;`. Your JavaScript code is very dirty and contains some errors like `jQuery(function($) {` inside of `jQuery(document).ready(function (){` and both are inside of `<body>`.

Comment: Finally it's very bad to use retro jqGrid version 4.4.3, which is 4.5 years old and which is dead since a long time. There are exist two main forks of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/), which I develop,  and commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which develop Tony Tomov. You should use the last version from one from the two forks.

Comment: Except that there are some code errors (which work instead) I have checked your code with the pure grid and data you posted (as from your post) and it is working. Check for errors into the code. Try with very simple setup - no if and etc

Comment: Thank oleg and tony. Now I used the jqGrid  5.2.1 and tried by removing if statment and jQuery(document).ready(function ().  Now error is same "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 78 of the JSON data".

Comment: @Dadu .Have a look into the fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/16129/** .It's working only with data & jqGrid... You need to add rest of your code.